# sync between git repo and non-git directory

Tags: git

I would like to find an efficient way of syncing files between a git repo and a target directory. The target directory in this case is the build location for an embedded linux distribution managed by ptxdist.

I am frequently building various versions of the distro so I set my various git repos to the corresponding commit, do an rsync to the build tree, and build the distro. The trouble with this approach is that rsync leaves files from one commit which may not exist in another commit and could cause confusion for the code.

I could make the distro a git repository and git pull into it but I don't need to track what I happen to be building.

The best candidate seems to be using git-archive to create tar files of the git repos, delete the target directories, then extract the tar files to the target directories. However, this seems inefficient if just a few files have changed out of everything that goes into the distro.

What I would like is a way to do something like an `rsync --delete`, or perhaps `unison -prefer`, with files in a git repository instead of the git working directory since I have untracked files I want to keep around.

UPDATE

Here is a bash script which I've used which does what was needed,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Does one way sync between commit and target directory where the target
# directory is not a git archive.
# USAGE: git-archive-commit <source directory> <target directory> [<treeish>] [-- <paths>...]
set -e
sourceDir="$(readlink -f $1)"
targetDir="$(readlink -f $2)"

shift; shift
checkoutArgs="$@"
gitSetup="--work-tree=$targetDir --git-dir=$sourceDir/.git"

function gitStash {
        pushd . > /dev/null 2>&1
        cd $targetDir
        git $gitSetup stash -q
        git $gitSetup stash drop -q > /dev/null 2>&1
        popd > /dev/null 2>&1
}

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then   
        if [ $1 != "--" ]; then
                if [ $# = 1 ]; then
                        gitStash
                fi
                git $gitSetup checkout $checkoutArgs
                shift
        else
                git $gitSetup checkout $checkoutArgs
        fi
else
        gitStash
        git $gitSetup checkout
fi
git $gitSetup clean -df "$@"
```

Comment: Would `git clean -x` along with `rsync --delete` help?

Comment: Surely one of the [delete options](http://superuser.com/a/156702) to rsync will do what you want, no?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I don't want to clean my untracked files in my source tree. It seems git has the information to sync with the repo instead of the working directory but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: DId I understand correctly you have some custom packages for a ptxdist based BSP, where you want to build arbitrary states of those packages, which are managed with Git outside of your BSP?

Comment: why can't the target be a git repository? Is that something to do with ptxdist or is that irrelevant?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn The target gets flashed to a production file system which doesn't need a development environment.

Comment: you are not allowed to install git on the production file system? Are you allowed to install other applications, such as rsync?

Answer (score 1):

If you "could make the distro a git repository and git pull into", that means:

- git is (or can be) available on the server
- the server can contact the client (while the reverse isn't obvious)

You could:

- make a bare repo on the server `/path/to/myrepo.git`
- set in it a post-update hook: `/path/to/myrepo.git/hooks/post-update`
- git pull

The post-update script can, after each pull, trigger a:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/target/directory --git-dir=/path/to/myrepo.git checkout HEAD
```

That would ignore the untracked files, but would update (add/modify/remove) the tracked file after each `git pull`.

Comment: @viw target is not a repo: that is the all point of using the --work-tree parameter.

Comment: I tried to do what I think you are suggesting but had some trouble. In this example, `/path/src` is the source git repository to pull from, `/path/myrepo`, is the empty repo from your example, and `/path/target` is the target directory, which is not a git repo.  If I put `git --work-tree=/path/target --git-dir=/path/myrepo checkout HEAD` in `/path/myrepo/.git/hooks/post-update` the files in `/path/src` wind up in `/path/myrepo` instead of `/path/target`.

Comment: @viw no, -git-dir is always the path to a git repo. I suggested a bare one. But if you specify a non-bare one, then it would be /path/to/repo/.git